# XML-RPC auto creates records, where web interface does not

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

I have a table that looks like this:

```
class fnx_sr_shipping(osv.Model):
    _name = 'fnx.sr.shipping'
    _description = 'shipping & receiving entries'
    _inherits = {
       'res.partner': 'partner_id',
       }
    _order = 'appointment_date desc, appointment_time asc'

    _columns = {

       .
       .
       .
       'partner_id': fields.many2one(
            'res.partner',
            'Partner',
            required=True,
            ondelete='restrict'),
       .
       .
       .
```

The `required=True` is required by OpenERP (if it's not there, OE adds it).

When I use the web interface I am able to create a new shipping record and pick existing partners; however, if I try the same thing using XML-RPC (supplying the `partner_id`s in the shipping record create call) OpenERP tries to create a new record in `res.partner` using default settings, which of course fails because some required fields have no default (such as the `name`).

Here's the XML-RPC code I'm using:

```
import openerplib
OE = PropertyDict()          # allows attribute-style access for keys
OE.conn = openerplib.get_connection(
        hostname='xxx',
        database='yyy',
        login='zzz',
        password='...'
OE.res_partner = conn.get_model('res.partner')
.
.
.
values['partner_id'] = 77     # or whatever it actually is ;)
OE.fnx_shipping.create(values)
```

I have verified that the `id`s being passed are correct.

Is this a bug in my code, or in OpenERP?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I worked around the problem by removing the `_inherits` and using functional fields to get the `res.partner` fields I was interested in.

Comment: If you just need a link to `res.partner` then no need to use `_inherits` in the model.

Comment: `_inherits` seemed like an easy way to get access in the `view` xml file -- and it worked just fine until I tried to use `xml-rpc`.

Comment: so you wanted to use the field of `res.partner` in the `fnx.sr.shipping`, isn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In browsing through `orm.py` I found this:

```
def name_create(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
    """Creates a new record by calling :meth:`~.create` with only one
       value provided: the name of the new record (``_rec_name`` field).

       The new record will also be initialized with any default values applicable
       to this model, or provided through the context.

       The usual behavior of :meth:`~.create` applies.
       Similarly, this method may raise an exception if the model has multiple
       required fields and some do not have default values.
    """
```

So I tried supplying the already existing `partner_id` in the `context` dict as

```
OE.fnx_shipping.create(values, context={'default_partner_id':partner_id})
```

I consider the whole mess a bug in OpenERP, but at least there is a not-horrible work-a-round.